# How to configure CKEditor to display centered pasted image?

Tags: node.js, angular, express, ckeditor5

I currently have a Classic themed editor configured in my angular app and my problem is that while pasting the image on the admin-side works fine as well as its positioning, it displays differently once it is retrieved on my client-side of the app. Moreover, larger images ignore the editor's container. Are there specific configurations for these?

As of now, these are my configurations configured in my angular component's HTML files.

```
 <ckeditor [editor]="Editor" data="" (change)="change($event)"  
                            [config]="{
                                toolbar: 
                                [ 'heading', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'link', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList', 'undo', 'redo' ],
                                heading: { 
                                    options: [
                                        { model: 'paragraph', title: 'Paragraph', class: 'ck-heading_paragraph' },
                                        { model: 'heading1', view: 'h1', title:'Heading 1', class: 'ck-heading_heading1' },
                                        { model: 'heading2', view: 'h2', title:'Heading 2', class: 'ck-heading_heading2' },
                                        { model: 'heading3', view: 'h3', title:'Heading 3', class: 'ck-heading_heading3' }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    }">
                            </ckeditor>
```

Comment: I did used ckeditor in a project and to display images in center, I did add a rule to css ``` figure {text-aligne: center;}```

Comment: Where is 'figure' referring to may I ask?

Comment: in my case for ckeditor 5, always ```img``` tag is warapped in ```figure``` tag... I think you could inspect ```img``` element in browser to see

Comment: Woah it worked! Just what I needed without extra configuration. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad I could help